# Get index of the Clicked item in YUI

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I have the following code.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="link"> link 1 </li>
    <li class="link"> link 2 </li>
    <li class="link"> link 3 </li>
    <li class="link"> link 4 </li>
</ul>\
```

**javaScript**

```
 YUI().use("node", function(Y){

    Y.all(".link").on("click", function(em){
       alert("you clicked on "+ index +"link .");
       node = em.currentTarget;
       node.addClass("clicked");
       // alert(node.get("class"));
    });
     alert(Y.all("li").get("class"));
});
```

I have two queries on this.

1) While first alert it should show class name "link" but it give alert of some YUI_23123_ random number. Why so?

2) And I want to alert the index also. example when user click on third link it should alert "you clicked on 3 link" and I also want to use this index value in other event as well.

How we can achieve the index?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/v9Zkd/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question!

For (1) Y.all(...) returns a NodeList.  Unfortunately the return value of "get" for a nodeList is oddly another NodeList, which gets interpreted in the printing of the alert to what you see.  Using "getAttribute" instead of "get" results in a more reasonable (though maybe not useful) output.

For (2) To achieve what you want,  you will need to either explicitly loop over the NodeList or use "delegate".  [Using "delegate"](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#delegation) is far more efficient for the page and allows you to insert "li" items dynamically, but the "indexOf" might get noticeably slow with hundreds or thousands of list items.

Using each:

```
Y.all(".link").each(function (node, index) {

    node.on("click", function(em){
        alert("you clicked on "+ index +" link.");
        node.addClass("clicked");
        alert(node.getAttribute("class"));
    });
});
```

Using delegate:

```
Y.one('ul').delegate("click", function (em) {
    var itemList =  em.container.all('li');;
    var node = em.currentTarget;
    alert("you clicked on "+ itemList.indexOf(node) +" link.");
    node.addClass("clicked");
    alert(node.getAttribute("class"));
}, 'li');
```

Answer (score 1):

About 1)...

One html element may have more than one class. YUI does insert some of it's generic classes and you get it, instead of your css class.
Also, you call get("class") on list of html elements which does't have to have the same css class, so I'm not sure how should get("class") behave properly that way.

I don't know what is your exact problem, but maybe hasClass() method could help you?
Or look at the Node api: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html